# Is it possible to have a main method with a @Before and @Test method in the same class? Java

Tags: java, junit, conceptual

I want to pass commandline arguments to a Java class with Junit test annotations, is this possible?

Example:

```
@Before
public void before(String a, String b) {
    // some processing
}

@Test
public void test() {

}

public static void main(String[] args) {

if (args[0] != null) 
    DEFAULT_CONTENT_DIR = args[0];

if (args[1] != null) 
    DEFAULT_FONTS_DIR = args[1];

if (args[2] != null) 
    formMLDir = args[2];

 before(DEFAULT_CONTENT_DIR, DEFAULT_FONTS_DIR);

}
```

Is something like this possible?

Comment: Generally unit testing methods aren't called from a `main` method but perhaps if you could explain what you are trying to achieve there might be a better way to do it.

Comment: I want to run 2 classes which have a symbiotic relationship. Class 1 produces output files which class 2 consumes and validates it. So I need to have a before method which does my setup and a unit test method which validates the output. I'm deploying these as jars in a production Linux environments, so the test data will differ depending on the box. So I need to be able to pass in command line arguments to the before method(which runs class1) so it knows where to get the production test data. I hope I provided sufficient context

Comment: To be honest I don't think this is a good use case for JUnit. It is designed for unit testing in which relationships to external classes are either very simple or mocked. I suggest you look at integration testing frameworks.

Comment: Try creating a different test method fir each type of configuration so all cinfigs are tested.  This way yiu wont need a before method and you'll have predictable results.

Answer (score 4):

Possible? Yes.  What you want? Probably not.

```
public class CustomeMain {

    public static void main(String [] args) {
        customSetup(args);
        JUnitCore.main(new String [] {"SomeTest"});
    }

}
```

The problem is that almost no one actually invokes JUnit themselves.  They use Ant, Maven, Eclipse, or some other build tool.  If this is the case then there your custom main method won't be called.

Also, despite the above comments, this type of testing is not inherently evil, but it is something that it is nice to avoid if possible but only if you can rewrite your application to avoid the complex interaction.  Don't just skip testing the interaction if you can't rewrite it.  If anyone gives you grief just tell them that this is an integration test and you are using JUnit as your integration test framework.

Likely, the easiest solution for you is to use environment variables or JVM properties.  Any half-decent build tool will have ways for you to supply this.  Get rid of the main method and change your before method to...

```
@Before
public void before() {
    String contentDir = System.getenv("CONTENT_DIR");
    if (contentDir == null) { 
        contentDir = DEFAULT_CONTENT_DIR;
    }

    //...
}
```